# ¿Cómo es la forma correcta de manipular los valores que tiene una API?

Tags: api

/*
De esta forma manipule la API para un proyecto.
¿Comó seria la mejor manera de manipular los valores de una API?
*/

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=100&category=21&difficulty=medium'; 
// Ajusta la URL de la API según sea necesario


//Funcion para obtener valores del API.
    async function fetchQuestions() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data.results;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching trivia questions:', error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta